# Problems with Mutex and distributed systems deadlocking

Tags: rust

I have n nodes running. All have an own mutex to the underlying data. They all request data from each other and have to lock their underlying mutex.
So it can occur that A waits for B and B waits for A.

In order to solve this I want to unlock the mutex while the request is performed. Unfortunately my current code looks like this

```
pub fn handle_message_send(data: Data<Mutex<HashMap<id,DataStruct>>){

let data = data.lock();

let data_mut = data.get_mut(id);

if let Some(data) = data_mut {

  for i in data.neighbors {
   
   //Perform data changes and reads
    do_reqwest();
    // Perform data changes and reads
   }
}
```

What I have tried:

I have tried to use `std::mem::drop` to drop the MutexGuard but it complains that data_mut is still around.

Other solutions with out of scope can be quite teadious as the loop is quite long and if I read data that represents an old state this can be a big problem.

Comment: If "performing the request" requires access to the data that is protected by the mutex, then you can't unlock it while the request is performed.  Moreover, even if you can unlock the mutex earlier, that might only reduce the likelihood of deadlocks rather than eliminate them.  In some distributed systems, it's not possible to totally eliminate deadlocks: perhaps you should simply manage them instead, e.g. by rolling back one participant and retrying later?

Comment: Distributed consistency is a lot more complicated than you think. The design you have simply won't work. You either need some consensus protocol, e.g. paxos or raft, *or* a transaction manager (which becomes a single point of failure, unless you use multiple instances, but then you again need a consensus protocol for coordination).

Comment: I agree with you both. For now I just constantly lock and unlock data. Hopefully this works. Otherwise I need to rely on a consensus protocol indeed but that would probably complicate the workflow.

Comment: If you don't need to *modify* the map itself during the loop, maybe you could protect each `DataStruct` individually? That way as long as two agents don't access the same entry at the same time you're fine. Also depending on what needs to be done, maybe `RwLock` would be a good idea?

Comment: You could also use `try_lock` so that the locking is non-waiting, although obviously it means agents don't *wait* for one another any more.

Comment: @Masklinn I already tried that. Unfortunately if the exact neighbors interlock each other. That becomes a problem too.